# On user login check other tabs having same website and reload those tabs

Tags: javascript, browser, gwt, tabs, reload

If login page is open in two tabs and user logs in to the first tab. I need to identify the other tab with login page and realod it.

I have tried to write various type of javascript but dont know how to write in gwt. Cannot find any feasible solution. I have one finding to get the current tab and realod it. But cannot identify that how can I get all the tab and their URL.

```
public static native void forceReload() /*-{
      $wnd.location.reload(true);
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know which other tabs are open on the same page/site, but you can communicate between them.

You could periodically (through a timer) check for a given cookie, or you could listen for changes in sessionStorage (setting a value from the tab where login happened).
You could also check with the server, using polling, long polling, server side events, or a websocket.

Comment: Hi thomas, It is not possible in gwt to access the web browser and get all the tabs with their url? and also thanks for your answer but it is little advance for me, if possible could you please share any gwt example related to it. thanks for you help.

Comment: It is not possible in the browser (in JS, and GWT compiles down to JS) to access the tabs and their URLs (unless you are a browser extension). For sessionStorage, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API, and use it through https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.elemental2/elemental2-webstorage/1.0.0-RC1 and https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.elemental2/elemental2-dom/1.0.0-RC1/elemental2/dom/Window.html#addEventListener-java.lang.String-elemental2.dom.EventListener-

Comment: Here there is an example of inter-tabs communication in GWT using web storage https://github.com/ibaca/intercomm-gwt/blob/master/src/main/java/intercomm/client/App.java